# How can I alter VerticalScroller's scrollerPosition from onScrollPositionChanged callback?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

As seen in code below I have a callback where I want to collect the `VerticalScroller`'s position, but if I do so, the VerticalScrollers widget will not scroll anymore, because in the source code to `VerticalScroller`, the initial callback has a call to `VerticalScroller` 's `scrollerPosition`. This value is not reachable from the callback where I want to use it. Is there a quick way to call the `scrollerPosition` or make the scrollbehavior continue ? (without creating a recursive "race" condition ?)

```
@Composable
fun StationsScreen(deviceLocation: LocationData, openDrawer: () -> Unit)
{

    var scrollPosition = ScrollPosition(0.px,0.px)

    FlexColumn {
        inflexible {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {Text(text = "Stations")},
                navigationIcon = {
                    VectorImageButton(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_24) {
                        openDrawer()
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        inflexible {
            Column (
                mainAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand,
                crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand
            ){

                LocationWidget(deviceLocation)
            }
        }
        inflexible {
            Column(
                mainAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand,
                crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand
            ){
                PushWidget(){
                    deviceLocation.lat++
                    deviceLocation.lng++
                }
            }
        }
        inflexible{
            Column(
                mainAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand,
                crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand
            ) {
                ScrollPosWidget(scrollPosition = scrollPosition)
            }
        }
        flexible(flex = 1f)
        {
            VerticalScroller (onScrollPositionChanged = { px: Px, px1: Px ->
                scrollPosition.posX = px
                scrollPosition.maxX = px1
            }){

                Column {

                    for(i in 0..20) {
                        HeightSpacer(16.dp)
                        imageBank.forEach { imageItem: ImageItem ->

                            Text(text = imageItem.title ?: "<Empty>")

                            Divider()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--- definition of the VerticalScroller Widget in compose source code:

```
@Composable
fun VerticalScroller(
    scrollerPosition: ScrollerPosition = +memo { ScrollerPosition() },
    onScrollPositionChanged: (position: Px, maxPosition: Px) -> Unit = { position, _ ->
        scrollerPosition.value = position
    },
    isScrollable: Boolean = true,
    @Children child: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    Scroller(scrollerPosition, onScrollPositionChanged, true, isScrollable, child)
}
```

Comment: can you share the link where there is a list of every UI component of compose?

Comment: @mudit_sen Thanx for commenting, apparently found a solution that works (see answer below), I will post this 'experiment' shortly on GitHub as public and link it here. There you will see the whole code.

RG

Comment: @mudit_sen Here's public link to the project. It will evolve as I get more experienced with Composable. https://github.com/RoarGronmo/EmptyFuel4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a solution for my problem... (I was sometime taught to think out of the box...) So...

In my `@Compose` function I actually need to create my own `scrollerPosition` instance and use that in my call to `VerticalScroller` to change the poisition. I was afraid that this could cause a recursive "race" call situation, but that dependends on when the `onScrolledPostionChanged` is called in the `Scroller`'s logic. If `onScrolledPositionChanged` is called when `scrollerPosition.position` changes value, you may get the recursive "race" condition. But apparently not.

So my changes are basicly like this:

```
@Composable
fun StationsScreen(deviceLocation: LocationData, openDrawer: () -> Unit)
{

    var scrollPosition = ScrollPosition(0.px,0.px)

    var myScrollerPosition = +memo{ ScrollerPosition ()}  //<--- make my own scrollerPosition

    FlexColumn {
        inflexible {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {Text(text = "Stations")},
                navigationIcon = {
                    VectorImageButton(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_24) {
                        openDrawer()
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        inflexible {
            Column (
                mainAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand,
                crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand
            ){

                LocationWidget(deviceLocation)
            }
        }
        inflexible {
            Column(
                mainAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand,
                crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand
            ){
                PushWidget(){
                    deviceLocation.lat++
                    deviceLocation.lng++
                }
            }
        }
        inflexible{
            Column(
                mainAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand,
                crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand
            ) {
                ScrollPosWidget(scrollPosition = scrollPosition)
            }
        }
        flexible(flex = 1f)
        {
            VerticalScroller (
                scrollerPosition = myScrollerPosition,
                onScrollPositionChanged = { px: Px, px1: Px ->
                    scrollPosition.posX = px
                    scrollPosition.maxX = px1
                    myScrollerPosition.value = px //<-- remember to set the new value here

                    // You can now use the difference of maxX and posX to load
                    // new items into the list...

            }){

                Column {

                    for(i in 0..20) {
                        HeightSpacer(16.dp)
                        imageBank.forEach { imageItem: ImageItem ->

                            Text(text = imageItem.title ?: "<Empty>")

                            Divider()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun LocationWidget(locationData: LocationData){

    Surface {
        Padding(padding = 8.dp) {
            Text(text = "${locationData.lat}, ${locationData.lng}")
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun PushWidget(action: () -> Unit){

    Surface {
        Padding(padding = 8.dp) {
            Button(text = "Click Me!", onClick = action)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScrollPosWidget(scrollPosition: ScrollPosition){
    Surface {
        Padding(padding = 8.dp) {
            Text(text = "posX=${scrollPosition.posX}, maxX=${scrollPosition.maxX}")
        }
    }
}
```

RG

Comment: There's a similar issue shortly explained by Bruno_ to make the VerticalScroller paged, that might help on his issue.

https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1573750997032100?thread_ts=1573745726.031700